# Spoof useragent using the firefox config file?

Tags: firefox, config, user-agent, spoofing

In firefox you can access a config by typing about:config into the adress bar. In this config how do you alter your useragent?

Comment: Try [to google](http://superuser.com/questions/98798/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-user-agent-via-aboutconfig) before asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an entry.

1. Right Click on about:config page
2. New -> String
3. Preference Name:  "general.useragent.override" -> OK
4. Add the value you want -> OK
5. You are ready, test your new user agent!

If you want to reset this value

1. Go to about:config
2. Right click on the preference "general.useragent.override"
3. Reset
4. You are ready (Note that the preference will stay empty, but the next time you will visit about:config will not be there)

If you want an easier way to change/toggle user agent I suggest you use an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=user%20agent).

Comment: Not valid with most recent versions of Firefox (e.g. 31).